# ESB or SCA -- Architectural perspective

Tags: service, esb, sca

How does modern day **ESB** compare to **SCA** ( in terms of routing / aggregating services ) ?

This is what i think [ from past experience ].

Lets say we have two services S1 and S2, and a composite service S3 which is composed of S1 and S2. Assume S1 and S2 have two different endpoints and protocols.

**How to access using ESB?**  ( WSO2 / Apache Synapse )

1. We can access S1 first and S2 second ( creating a pipe )
2. We can access S3 directly to provide output.
   (protocol conversion / transformation / orchestration ) being done here.

**How to access using SCA?**  ( Apache Tuscany )

1. Lookup S1 first and S2 next ( using SCA API )
2. Create a composite S3 out of S1 and S2 and invoke S3
   ( protocol conversion / transformation / orchestration ) being done here.

Are people out there using both SCA composition and ESB Orchestration together?

Comment: IBM's Websphere ESB is built on SCA. There, each consumed service is represented by an SCA import that can be then used in an ESB mediations (routing, transformation...). The mediation is a SCA component too, that can be exposed as a service, or used in other compositions. There is something on the topic here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/esbsoa/wesbv7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wesb.overview.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcovw_sca.html . And I'm sure they also have a Redbook (http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks.nsf/portals/) on this.

Answer (score 1):

SCA is not an alternative to ESB It's just a way to build Service Oriented Architecture.

As david.a says you could use an oriented SCA ESB like Websphere ESB, or Oracle SOA-suite which is an SCA oriented integration solution.

You could learn more about SCA here : http://www.davidchappell.com/writing/Introducing_SCA.pdf

In Oracle and IBM usage, SCA composition is a way to combined different kind of implementation, It could be use to build a solution with a mediation part (ESB) in front of another element (BPEL, java bean etc...).

From a Service Oriented Architecture view, SCA help you to combined your ESB with your upper layer (BPEL, BR etc...)